# Perl6: Cannot invoke this object (REPR: P6opaque; Parallel::ForkManager)

Tags: raku

I'm attempting to run a series of shell commands in parallel in Perl6, using Perl5's `Parallel::ForkManager` 
This is an almost exact translation of working Perl5 code.

```
CONTROL {
    when CX::Warn {
        note $_;
        exit 1;
    }
}
use fatal;
role KeyRequired {
    method AT-KEY (\key) {
        die "Key {key} not found" unless self.EXISTS-KEY(key);
        nextsame;
    }
}

use Parallel::ForkManager:from<Perl5>;

sub run_parallel (@cmd) {
    my $manager = Parallel::ForkManager(8).new();
    for (@cmd) -> $command  {
        $manager.start and $manager.next;
        my $proc = shell $command, :out, :err;
        if $proc.exitcode != 0 {
            put "$command failed";
            put $proc.out.slurp;
            put $proc.err.slurp;
            die;
        }
        $manager.finish;
    }
    $manager.wait_all_children;#necessary after all lists
}

my @cmd;
my Str $dir = 'A/1';
for dir($dir, test => /\.vcf\.gz$/) -> $vcf {
    @cmd.append: "aws s3 cp $vcf s3://s3dir/$dir/"
}
put @cmd.elems;
run_parallel(@cmd);
```

Basically, I'm trying to parallelize tedious shell commands.

However, this mysterious error comes up:

> Cannot invoke this object (REPR: P6opaque; Parallel::ForkManager)   in
>   sub run_parallel at 2.aws_cp.p6 line 18   in block  at
>   2.aws_cp.p6 line 39

Why is Perl6 saying this? what is wrong? how can I get these commands to run?

Perhaps there is a more native/idiomatic way to run shell commands in parallel in Perl6?

Comment: I really would not advise trying to use Perl5 forking code in Perl6 it's got a completely different system for manager asynchronous and parallel code.

Comment: "forking" is the correct term for what this is trying to do, i.e. run shell commands in parallel? @Scimon

Comment: I get that. My point was Perl6 doens't use Forking for parallel work instead using threads.

Comment: Others have pointed out why they think P5's `Parallel::ForkManager` seems unlikely to work with P6. I have no knowledge about this one way or the other. The following is completely independent of this and is instead about using P6 with P5 in a way that involves threads. Per [the BUILDING section of the Inline::Perl5 README](https://github.com/niner/inline-perl5#building), "if you want to use more than one `Inline::Perl5` interpeter safely, for instance from within Perl 6 threads, add the `-Dusemultiplicity` option as well".

Answer (score 7):

You probably want to look at using [Proc::Async](https://docs.raku.org/type/Proc::Async) which runs external commands asynchronously in threads without forking separate instances of the code to do it.

Comment: maybe even give the module [Proc::Q](https://github.com/perl6-community-modules/perl6-Proc-Q) a go, it's meant for situations where you have lots of processes you want to run in parallel.

Answer (score 5):

Perl5's *Parallel::ForkManager* probably won't work in Perl6 because of how *Inline::Perl5* is implemented.

*Inline::Perl5* embeds the Perl5 compiler/runtime inside of Perl6.

*Parallel::ForkManager* expects that Perl5 was run by itself.

If you ever did get it to do something other than generate an error it would probably screw up the Perl6 runtime. The main problem is the use of `fork`. For more information about why `fork` is a a problem see the article Bart Wiegmans (brrt) wrote about it: [“A future for fork(2)”](https://brrt-to-the-future.blogspot.com/2018/10/a-future-for-fork2.html)

---

Perl6 already has a similar feature that is easier to use.

```perl6
sub run_parallel (@cmd) {
    my @children = do for (@cmd) -> $command  {
        start {
            my $proc = shell $command, :out, :err;
            if $proc.exitcode != 0 {
                put "$command failed";
                put $proc.out.slurp;
                put $proc.err.slurp;
                die;
            }
        }
    }
    await @children;
}
```

`start` is a prefix that tells the runtime to start running the following code sometime in the near future. It returns a *Promise*.
`await` takes a list of *Promise*s and returns a list of their results.

`start` basically calls `Promise.start` which is similar to:

```perl6
sub start ( &code ) {
    my $promise = Promise.new;
    my $vow = $promise.vow;

    $*SCHEDULER.cue(
        { $vow.keep(code(|c)) },
        :catch(-> $ex { $vow.break($ex); }) );
    $promise
}
```

So it will use the globally available thread pool in `$*SCHEDULER`. If you want to use a separate one you could.

```perl6
sub run_parallel (@cmd) {
    my $*SCHEDULER = ThreadPoolScheduler.new(max_threads => 8);

    my @children = do for (@cmd) -> $command  {
        start {
            my $proc = shell $command, :out, :err;
            if $proc.exitcode != 0 {
                put "$command failed";
                put $proc.out.slurp;
                put $proc.err.slurp;
                die;
            }
        }
    }
    await @children;
}
```

It would make more sense to use *Proc::Async* for this though.